# Can't assign C# variable value properly when using Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, variables, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting unexpected output in my unity C# code.

```js
string currentScore = "origData";

fb.reference.Database
      .GetReference("scores")
      .Child(userId)
      .GetValueAsync()
      .ContinueWith(task => {
        if(task.IsFaulted){
          Debug.Log("Error");
        }else if(task.IsCompleted){
                        Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
          Debug.Log("Inside :"+currentScore);
          currentScore = snapshot.Value.ToString();
          Debug.Log("Inside Updated:"+currentScore);
        }
      });
Debug.Log("Outside: "+currentScore);
```

`Debug.Log("Outside: "+currentScore);` was executed first before `fb.reference.Database`. So the output was
`Outside: origData`,
`Inside: origData`,
`Inside Updated: firebaseResponse`. I am expecting to execute `fb.reference.Database` before the `Debug.Log("Outside: "+currentScore);`

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the method:

```
fb.reference.Database .GetReference("scores") .Child(userId) .GetValueAsync()
```

As the method call states, you're calling an asynchronous method. So you're program will continue the execution of the caller method and you'll get the results after the:

```
Debug.Log("Outside: "+currentScore);
```

You should probably call a synchronous method (if exists), or move the 'Debug.Log' line into the 'ContinueWith' task:

```
fb.reference.Database .GetReference("scores") .Child(userId) .GetValueAsync() .ContinueWith(task => { Debug.Log("Outside: "+currentScore); ...
```